# File image onloaded is not called after calling readAsDataURL on large images

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to read an image file and resize and upload it in Ionic2 on Android. My code works for small size images, but for images that are more than 3MB, the onloaded function is never called.

I really appreciate any help or insight as to why.

```
makeFileIntoBlob(_imagePath) {


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( _imagePath, fileEntry => {

            fileEntry.file(file => {

                var reader = new FileReader();

                console.log('Reading the file!');

                reader.onloadend = (e: any) => {

                    var img = document.createElement("img");


                    img.onload = () => {
                        //---> Only get here for small images!
                        var resizedImg =  this.imgResizerSrvc.resize(img, 480, 480);
                        var imgBlob: any = this.dataURLtoBlob(resizedImg);
                        imgBlob.name = 'sample.jpg';
                        console.log('makeFileIntoBlob resolved!');
                        resolve(imgBlob);
                    }

                    //Will trigger img.onloadend
                    alert("about to trigger");
                    img.src = e.target.result;  //----> This call only triggeres reader.onloadend for small images
                    alert("Done trigger");

                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            });
        });
    });
```

}

As an alternative, I have also tried reading the file using the following:

```
img.src = (window.URL ? URL : window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( file );
```

or

```
img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL || window || {}).createObjectURL( file );
```

but none of these trigger img.onloaded().

Comment: What does `.dataURLtoBlob` do? What does `this.imgResizerSrvc.resize(img, 480, 480);` return? There could be a limitation on `.length` of `data URI`. Does `.this` inside `.onload` reference `img` element?

Comment: They are for resizing and converting to a blob. My problem right now is that I don't even get to those functions to be called, so the problem should not be in there. This code is a member function of a component in ionic2, so I expected `.this` is referencing that component. But again, my problem is that `img.onload` doesn't even get called.

Comment: `this` within `img` `load` event would be `<img>` element. There could be a limit on the `.length` of the `data URI`. You could use `Blob` instead of `data URI`. `file` is a `File` object, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a limitation on the `.length` of the `data URI`

> **Length limitations**
>
> Although Firefox supports data URIs of essentially
>   unlimited length, browsers are not required to support any particular
>   maximum length of data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limited data
>   URIs to around 65000 characters.

You could use `URL.createObjectURL()` called on `file`, without using `FileReader()`, pass `Blob` created by `.imgResizerSrvc.resize` to `File()` to set the `.name` of the create `File` object.

```
makeFileIntoBlob(_imagePath) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(_imagePath, fileEntry => {

      fileEntry.file(file => {

        var component = /* reference to ionic2 component */ ;

        var img = document.createElement("img");

        img.onload = () => {

          var resizedImg = component.imgResizerSrvc.resize(this, 480, 480);
          var imgBlob = new File([resizedImg], "sample.jpg", {
            type: "image/jpeg"
          });
          resolve(imgBlob);

        };

        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried your code, but my code crashes on this line:         img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); This happens with any size image.
I did some research, the other suggested ways didn't work either:
`img.src = (window.URL ? URL : window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( file );`
or

`img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL || window || {}).createObjectURL( file );`

Any ideas what I'mmissing?

Comment: What is `file`?

Comment: From my understanding it's just an object that is returned by window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL. I have taken my code from here: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/firebaseStorage2/blob/master/app/pages/home/home.ts

Comment: What does `console.log(file)` log at `console`?

Comment: Ah, it's an object that has name, `localURL`, `type`, `lastModified`, `lastModifiedDate`, `size`, `start`, and `end` fields, but the file object here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File`, is slightly different. How do I convert them? the fields are all read only.

Comment: Is there a method within the API to convert the object to a `Blob`? Have you tried requesting `localURL` as a `Blob` at `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()`?

Comment: There is this:               `var imgBlob: any = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg' });`

Comment: The API's I believe are these: 
`interface Blob {
    readonly size: number;
    readonly type: string;
    msClose(): void;
    msDetachStream(): any;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
}

declare var Blob: {
    prototype: Blob;
    new (blobParts?: any[], options?: BlobPropertyBag): Blob;
}`

Comment: Can you create `Blob` from `file`? Is `URL.createObjectURL` defined?

Comment: Yes: `declare var URL: {
    prototype: URL;
    new(url: string, base?: string): URL;
    createObjectURL(object: any, options?: ObjectURLOptions): string;
    revokeObjectURL(url: string): void;
}
`

Comment: Does creating `Blob` from `file`, using `URL.createObjectURL` should resolve issue?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The main problem in my first comment was that                     img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); crashed the app.

Comment: Why did app crash?

Comment: The call at `URL.createObjectURL` never finishes. I put an alert after this call, the control never reaches that line. Unfortunately, I cannot see any console log resulting from the execution of URL.createObjectURL because something is messed up with my Android studio debugging.

Comment: Have you tried setting `img` `src` to `localURL` property of `file`?

Comment: So is this method considered safe and can be used for large pictures (like 10MB)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "safe"? Have you tried images over 10MB? Is there a storage quota for the filesystem where files are stored?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a quota. This is running on an Android or Iphone phone.